# Ошибка при использовании производных типов данных MPI

Tags: c++, распараллеливание, mpi

```
bool isComposite(int num) {
    if (num < 2) return false;
    for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt(num); ++i) {
        if (num % i == 0) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int rank, size;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    srand(time(0));

    int rows_per_proc = M / size;
    int extra_rows = M % size;

    int* sendcounts = new int[size];
    int* displs = new int[size];

    vector<int> matrix(M * N);
    vector<int> local_data;

    if (rank == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < M * N; ++i) {
            matrix[i] = rand() % 100;
        }
        cout << "Original Matrix:" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
                cout << matrix[i * N + j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    // Расчет количества и смещения для блочного распределения данных
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        sendcounts[i] = (i < extra_rows) ? (rows_per_proc + 1) : rows_per_proc;
        displs[i] = (i > 0) ? (displs[i - 1] + sendcounts[i - 1]) : 0;
    }

    // Создание производного типа данных MPI для блока
    MPI_Datatype block_type;
    MPI_Type_vector(sendcounts[rank], N, N * size, MPI_INT, &block_type);
    MPI_Type_create_resized(block_type, 0, N * sizeof(int), &block_type); 
    MPI_Type_commit(&block_type);


    local_data.resize(sendcounts[rank] * N);

    MPI_Scatterv(matrix.data(), sendcounts, displs, block_type, local_data.data(), sendcounts[rank] * N, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Type_free(&block_type);

    cout << "Process " << rank << " - local data:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < sendcounts[rank] * N; ++i) {
        cout << local_data[i] << " ";
        if ((i + 1) % N == 0) cout << endl;
    }

    double start_time = MPI_Wtime();
    // Обработка локальных данных
    for (int i = 0; i < sendcounts[rank] * N; ++i) {
        if (isComposite(local_data[i])) {
            local_data[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    double end_time = MPI_Wtime();

    MPI_Gatherv(local_data.data(), sendcounts[rank] * N, MPI_INT, matrix.data(), sendcounts, displs, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank == 0) {
        cout << "Modified Matrix:" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
                cout << matrix[i * N + j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }

        cout << "Execution time for " << size << " processes: " << (end_time - start_time) * 1000 << " sec." << endl;
    }

    delete[] sendcounts;
    delete[] displs;

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

При запуске программы с 4 процессами выводиться ошибка:
Fatal error in MPI_Scatterv: Message truncated, error stack:
MPI_Scatterv(sbuf=0x00000270885386F0, scnts=0x000002708853D600, displs=0x000002708853DA10, dtype=USER, rbuf=0x0000027088520D40, rcount=16, MPI_INT, root=0, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
Message truncated; 64 bytes received but buffer size is 64

Как её исправить? Она появилась после того, как я добавил строки

```
 MPI_Datatype block_type;
    MPI_Type_vector(sendcounts[rank], N, N * size, MPI_INT, &block_type);
    MPI_Type_create_resized(block_type, 0, N * sizeof(int), &block_type); 
    MPI_Type_commit(&block_type);


    local_data.resize(sendcounts[rank] * N);

    MPI_Scatterv(matrix.data(), sendcounts, displs, block_type, local_data.data(), sendcounts[rank] * N, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Type_free(&block_type);
```